# Every infinite linearly ordered set has two disjoint infinite subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to the [Wikipedia Page on amorphous sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), no amorphous set can be totally ordered. If I am correct, this states that every infinite totally ordered set has two disjoint infinite subsets, but I am not sure how to go about proving it in ZF (if it is even provable in ZF), although here's my attempt:

Every infinite totally ordered set $S$ has either an infinitely decreasing or infinitely increasing subset, so I tried considering such a subset $A$. Without loss of generality, suppose $A$ is increasing. Then, letting $a_{1}$ be an element in $A$, the set $A_{1}:=\{a\in A\mid a>a_{1}\}$ is infinite and thus non-empty. Now, let $a_{2}$ be an element of $\{a\in A|a>a_{1}\}$. Since $a_{2}\in A$, the set $A_{2}:=\{a\in A\mid a>a_{2}\}$ is nonempty, and we can continue in this way to generate a sequence $\{a_{1},a_{2},\dots\}$.

My problem is that I rather suspect I just used the axiom of countable choice if not something stronger. Is there a way of proving this in ZF alone?

Comment: What does "infinitely decreasing subset" mean for a set that might be amorphous? Such sets son't even have _infinite sequences_ of their elements, so you can't be talking of whether such a sequence is decreasing...

Comment: Hmm, on further thought what you probably mean there is "a subset with no least element" instead of "infinitely decreasing". Then the rest of the argument does make sense. (But I'm not sure the existence of such a set doesn't itself require some form of choice).

Comment: What is an example of amorphous set?

Comment: @mathpadawan According to Wikipedia: “Fraenkel constructed a permutation model of ZFA in which the set of atoms is amorphous.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof attempt does indeed depend not only on countable choice, but on *dependent* choice.

Here's an argument that doesn't:

Suppose $S$ is infinite and totally ordered. If we can find even one element that has both infinitely many predecessors and infinitely many successors, then $S$ is surely not amorphous.¹

Thus the elements of $S$ fall into two classes, namely those with only finitely many *predecessors* and those with only finitely many *successors*. At least one of those classes must be infinite; without loss of generality let's suppose that there are infinitely many elements that have finitely many predecessors.

However, in a *total* order there can be at most one element that has, for example, exactly 42 predecessors. So counting predecessors gives us an injection from an infinite subset of $S$ into $\mathbb N$, which means that this subset is *countable* and $S$ is therefore not amorphous.

---

¹: Note that this apparently unassuming first step is in fact critical to the argument; without it everything unravels. It *is* consistent with ZF that there may be an infinite totally ordered set that *has no countably infinite subset*. (Cohen showed a model in which $\mathbb R$, definitely totally orderable, has a subset with this property.)

Comment: +1 (I was still typing when this appeared.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass: It must be right if we both come up with it! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is provable in ZF. Let $S$ be an infinite linearly ordered set; I'll try to produce two disjoint, infinite subsets of $S$. First, for any $s\in S$, consider the set $A_s$ of elements above $s$ in the linear ordering and the set $B_s$ of elements below $s$. If, for some $s$, both $A_s$ and $B_s$ are infinite, we're done, because they're certainly disjoint.

So from now on, we can assume that, for each $s$, one of $A_s$ and $B_s$ is finite (and the other must then be infinite because $S$ is infinite). Without loss of generality, assume there are infinitely many $s$ with $B_s$ finite. (If that's not the case, then, as $S$ is infinite, there will be infinitely many $s$ with $A_s$ finite, and the following argument will apply to the reversed linear ordering.)

For each of the infinitely many $s$ with $B_s$ finite, $|B_s|$ is a natural number, and these natural numbers are different for different $s$. So we have a one-to-one map $f:s\mapsto |B_s|$ of an infinite subset of $S$ into $\mathbb N$. But the image of that map (which in fact is all of $\mathbb N$ but I don't need that) can be split into two infinite pieces by taking alternating elements of it.  The inverse images of those pieces under $f$ are two disjoint infinite subsets of $S$, as required.